# PHP & Adobe AIR RIA's

Tags: php, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, amf

First and foremost - I am sorry if this is a question that has been answered hundreds of times on this site. When I typed the topic in it came back with a ton of related threads, and after reading through the majority I have found no CLEAR answer to my following questions. So here they are (may the flaming begin...)

I am building an inventory control type of application that houses a mySQL database online. I want to distribute a select few copies of this program via desktop application to customers of mine to check their inventories. So the question is, I guess, do I even want to use Adobe AIR to do this with or should I stick to the web only type of format. And secondly, is AIR capable of dealing with the same kind of PHP/AMF requests being asked of it. (I read somewhere that AIR only supports HTTPService type calls and not RemoteObject)

I hope this makes sense. I just don't know all of the limitaitons, if any, that AIR has versus a standard output the the web. The reason I want the AIR app is to restrict the people even using this application. (I will give copies via CD/DVD to ONLY my customers who need to access their current inventories.)

Thank you in advance to all who respond. And again, I am very sorry if this has been answered time and time again - I truly did try and do my homework.

-CS

Answer (score 2):

Actually AIR expands on the existing ActionScript API. It is in no way more limited than a pure web application (whoever wrote that article on 'remoting' not being supported in AIR doesn't know the first thing about it). On the contrary, AIR can do lots of things that web-apps can't: native windows, dock icons, local databases, drag&drop from your desktop, interacting with applications on your desktop, ... just to name a few.

The thing I would worry most about in your story is this: **how are you going to get it installed?** You have to know that if you want to install an AIR app, you need to first install the AIR runtime (much like Java).

You would like to distribute via CD.

- Do your customers have the right to install any software on their PC's?
- If they do, they still will need to install the AIR runtime first. Are the allowed to do that.
- If you answered yes to the 2 previous questions: how are you going to explain them to first install the runtime and then the AIR app itself? It makes the installation procedure far more daunting for non-tech users.

One last question: what's wrong with a secure web-app and giving your customers a username/password to log in?

Comment: Thank you for your response RIAstar - To answer some of your questions. I would be bundling the AIR runtime with the CD's. But you do bring up a VERY valid point - and that is the right to install on their systems. THAT I do not know for every customer. I'd guess that 95% do have the right...But that leaves 5% that can not and that is a problem and huge limitation. I really like the AIR idea from the stand point though that it seems more secure and I can define a finite value for window size....Keeping my UI intact. And, lastly, nothing is wrong with a web-app...Just concerned about security..

Comment: Just be aware that if you're planning on distributing the AIR runtime on your CD, you need to get a "license" from Adobe. See: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html

Comment: I'll just add, I've gotten permission from Adobe for the runtime distro, it didn't cost anything and was easy to get.

Comment: +1.  This is the right answer, but to expand on it a bit, if you use Air, you can 'save' the inventory data for offline purposes (if not connected to the net, like on the road with your laptop).  Of course, the data might not be accurate, but it's still a nice feature to have in Air.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would say that Air is overkill. If the data was supposed to be kept client side, that would be one thing -- Air does have a built-in database, but you're not. In fact, in order to get the application work you need to have internet access and one of the major point of Air is that it is a desktop application.

As to detriments of Air vs. Flash in functionality? None that I know of. Actually, Air has a lot of bonuses: direct, file system read/write/execute access; a built in database; and, because there is no worry about ActiveX vs. browser extension, I will wager that there is greater consistency under Windows (although I have seen at least one bizarre difference under Mac). On Windows there is even a special installer which will install Air and then your application in Air. Of course, on Mac and Linux, you'll need to give them step by step instructions.

The thing is, in your case, I don't see any of those being any real help to you over what you could do in a browser. In a browser, you can ensure that you know your clients are using version 3.2.11 instead of having to have them go to the help and say "read me the version you see on your machine." Finally, with Air, if you don't have an SSL certificate you have to buy one otherwise the application will come across as "unknown author" and certain security policies will go bananas -- $400 isn't much, but it is annoying.

Comment: Well - I really appreciate the quick response. The SSL certificate if not problem, as I planned on pulling one anyhow (web app or desktop version) - I do like the idea of having it on the internet only for the reason that they could work from anywhere they are - but do you think I am 'wrong' in the assumption that if I distributed the app via CD it would be more secure? Mainly from prying eyes and "hackers" - The local competition may see what I'm doing and use a decompiler to get my source??? Paranoid? Safe? Help. :-)   Thanks again for your input!

Comment: I don't think "local storage" is the only reason to choose AIR; although it is definitely one benefit over a browser based app. I also wanted to add that AIR has an update mechanism, so you can prompt the user to upgrade automatically. meaning they should--in theory--always have the correct version.  In practice, I don't think you can force the users to upgrade.

Comment: @Chad S I don't think the app distribution mechanism makes the app more secure.  Even if you were to distribute the app on CD; I would still authenticate users from within the app before giving them access to sensitive data.  I doubt the AIR app would be as easy to access as a Web app; but ease or difficultly of access does not make the app any more, or less, secure.

Comment: @Flextras I never said it was the only reason. I only listed three which came to mind immediately. You can force upgrade in that you can do some remote request (HTTP, SOAP, RPC... etc) and shut down if their version is sufficiently different, but it is annoying.

Comment: @Chad S. There is very little you can do to secure Air which you can't do with HTTP authentication over HTTPS.

Comment: Well - thanks again to everyone who helped me out with this. I am still kicking around the idea of AIR vs. Web - But I think I'm leaning more toward the Web version, simply because then the users could access the program from anywhere. As long as the app's security remains a top priority.

Comment: Again though - thank you to everyone who responded....{I accidentally hit the Enter key last time and it posted the message, whoops!}